# how to fix view overlapping a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a textview and above it is recyclerview. the content in the recyclerview comes under the top textview which I want to avoid.

in another way(that top textview is being over the recyclerview. how to fix that)?

[image]

here is card_view `

```
    android:id="@+id/chakra_list_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chakra_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/crown" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chakra_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chakra_icon"
            android:text="Crown"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`
```

main activity :

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chakra_list_title_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Choose a Chakra"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chakra_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/chakra_list_title_tv"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp" />
```

Comment: It would really help if you provided a snippet of your code. Otherwise, we have no idea what's exactly happening and how to fix it.

Comment: sorry about that! code added.

Comment: Please add complete code snippet, don't copy/paste the parts.

Answer (score 0):

Set `clipToPadding` of your RecyclerView to `"true"`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chakra_list_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/chakra_list_title_tv"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp" />
```

Comment: Try it together with paddingTop="16dp"